# How to show custom JSX on the top of the webpage for web extension

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am using this boilerplate code https://github.com/Jonghakseo/chrome-extension-boilerplate-react-vite .
The use case is, if the user clicks a context menu that is associated with the web extension, it should open a JSX modal on the current webpage.

**background.ts**

```
import reloadOnUpdate from 'virtual:reload-on-update-in-background-script';
import 'webextension-polyfill';

reloadOnUpdate('pages/background');

/**
 * Extension reloading is necessary because the browser automatically caches the css.
 * If you do not use the css of the content script, please delete it.
 */
reloadOnUpdate('pages/content/style.scss');

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  console.log('onInstalled....');

  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'typelessPopup',
    title: 'Add to typless',
    contexts: ['selection'],
  });
  chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    chrome.storage.local.set({ selectedText: info.selectionText });
   });
});

console.log('background loaded', chrome);
```

What are the code changes I have to make according to the boilerplate code ?

Answer (score 1):

To show custom modal on current page as reaction to context menu click you'll need

1. Inject contentscript into page. This can be done by directly specifying content script and associated URL(s) in manifest or at the moment when user clicks context menu item by using [chrome.scripting.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/scripting#method-executeScript) API. Specifying it in manifest will be easier to implement, but it depends on your extension.
2. In your content script you'll need to attach [message listener](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/messaging) which will listen for specific message and open modal when such message arrives.
3. Once user clicks context menu item you'll need to inject content script (if you didn't add it to manifest beforehand). And then you send message to current tab with selected text.
4. In content script this will trigger message handler where you can inject modal into page. How you do this depends on which libraries you use for UI. In case of React you can use library like [inject-react-anywhere](https://github.com/OlegWock/inject-react-anywhere), it will make it easier. Or you can do it without libraries by using [`createRoot` function](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot) from react-dom, rendering your modal there and appending root to the page.